# Why js ignores '{}' in statements like '{}[0]'?

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain why and describe how JavaScript converts statements like

```
{}[0]   => [0]
{}.2    => 0.2
{}'foo' => 'foo'
```

Comment: Compare it to `{console.log("wat")}[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your case `{}` **isn't** an object literal, but just empty blocks. 
You can use code blocks anywhere to improve readability. Also, such blocks can be useful when working with labels.

```
label: {
  // some code
}
```

Remember the curly braces after `if` condition? They're code blocks too.

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` in your code is simply creating an empty Object, but doing nothing with it. The part directly after it is treated as a separate statement.

For instance:

```
{}var foo = 1;
```

This will create a `foo` variable with the value `1` assigned to it. The `{}` is parsed and an empty Object is created, but nothing happens with it as we aren't doing anything with it. The `{}` may as well be on a different line altogether:

```
{}
var foo = 1;
```

So in the three examples you've provided:

```
{}    => Object {}      // Creates empty object but does nothing with it.
[0]   => [0]            // As expected.
```

```
{}    => Object {}      // Creates empty object but does nothing with it.
.2    => 0.2            // As expected.
```

```
{}    => Object {}      // Creates empty object but does nothing with it.
'foo' => 'foo'          // As expected.
```

Comment: I don't think it's an empty object. I believe it's code block.

because if it was an object I should be able to do this then:

{x:5}["x"] // returns 5

instead it returns ["x"]

Comment: But why it doesn't return `undefined`.
    `var a = {};
    a['bar']   //undefined`

Comment: @Edwin as I explained they're different statements. `{x:5}` will return `Object { x: 5 }`, `["x"]` will return `["x"]`.

Comment: @azum that's a completely different question. `a['bar']` is `undefined` because your `a` object has no `bar` property.